# Invalid Coordinate Supplied issue in iOS MAUI

Tags: ios, maui

I'm passing coordinates through API service in my MAUI project, below is the API method:

```
 public static async Task<List<Shop>> GetShops(double customerLat, double customerLong)
        {
            var httpClient = new HttpClient();
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", Preferences.Get("accessToken", string.Empty));
            var response = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(AppSettings.ApiUrl + "api/Shops?userLat=" + customerLat +"&userLong=" + customerLong);
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Shop>>(response);
        }
```

This works fine in Android but in iOS for some reason the supplied coordinates are not interpreted as decimal points. For example, if I supplied the latitude and longitude as 26.590354 and 49.972707 respectively, it will be read in the server as 26590354 and 49972707 which is obviously invalid geocoordinates. When setting the coordinates explicitly in the GetStringAsync method, it works fine. Your kind support is appreciated.

Comment: what is the actual value of the string being passed to `GetStringAsync` in both platforms?  Is it the same?  Have you tried explicitly setting the string format instead of using the default?  Have you checked the actual value being received by the server?

Comment: Are latitude and longitude always the same in server if using different values?

Comment: It is different.

Comment: when I set the GetStringAsync explicitly, it worked:  var response = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(AppSettings.ApiUrl + "api/Shops?userLat=26.987&userLong=49.97");

Comment: The different i think is the type. Try converting double customerLat&customerLong to string and then pass to API

Comment: I tried converting to string but still same issue:  AppSettings.ApiUrl + "api/Shops?userLat=" + customerLat.ToString() +"&userLong=" + customerLong.ToString()

Comment: I think it needs more debug. If the parameter string passed into the  GetStringAsync  is the same, why api get different value.

Comment: The strange thing it works fine in android, so there is no reason why it shouldn’t work in iOS since the same API is used. Could it be a bug in iOS ?